Mass of the Prototype $\rm kg$
With the new SI kg based upon Planck's constant $h$, is there any plan to eventually measure the former IPK using a Watt Balance, and determine how far its mass deviates from the new definition of 1 kg?

BIPM have some related articles, eg "Calibration campaign against the international prototype of the kilogram in anticipation of the redefinition of the kilogram" https://www.bipm.org/en/mass-metrology/ipk
